# Keep tab active state, and open tab by default

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I've made a jsfiddle of my rough setup here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9h5eqsuy/1/

a) My issue is I have tabs working fairly well, but it won't keep the active purple state once its clicked. I've tried a few solutions to no avail.

b) Additionally, I cant figure out how to have "item 1" tab open by default when you load the page.

I would like to avoid javascript if possible. Any thoughts would be great.

HTML

```
<p>
  <div class="tabbuttonsdiv">
    <a href="#item1" class="tabbuttons">item 1</a>
    <a href="#item2" class="tabbuttons">item 2</a>
    <a href="#item3" class="tabbuttons">item 3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="items">
    <p id="item1" class="tabcontent">... item 1...
    <p id="item2" class="tabcontent">... item 2...
    <p id="item3" class="tabcontent">...      
  </div>
</p>
```

CSS

```
div.items p {
    display: none;
}

div.items p:target {
    display: block;
}

.tabbuttons{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#3195c1;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.tabbuttons:hover {
    background-color:PURPLE;
}
.tabcontent{
    background: #ddd;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

A final question if anyone is feeling generous:

c) At the moment I can't put div's or anything inside the "here" below:

```
<p id="item1" class="tabcontent">... "here"... </p>
```

It only seems to like text, and butchers anything I paste into it. Is their any easy way to remedy this?

Answer (score 3):

a) you can add an `class="active"` to the current active tab, to keep the color

b) you can use this same `active` class to show a tab by default.

c) you can't nest `<div>` under a `<p>`, but there's no reason you can't make your `<p class="tabcontent">` into `<div class="tabcontent">`.

I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9h5eqsuy/2/

Comment: How are you going to add the class `active` without Javascript (or jQuery)? This is what the OP wants and I'm actually really curious if it's possible :D

Comment: Oh! You could probably do it by using the same class on the button and the tab, and targeting on the class name, with css to change the background of the button. I'll see if I can mock it up.

Comment: So, I think the closest thing to the functionality for tabs without javascript is using radio buttons. I've tried to put something together like this, but it's very buggy. https://jsfiddle.net/9h5eqsuy/7/

Clicking the text will change the button/highlighting, but clicking the box will activate the anchor link... buggy.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged jQuery in your question, I came up with this solution.

CSS:

```
div.items p {display: none}
div.items p:first-child {display: block; } /* solution for b. */

.tabbuttons{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#3195c1;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.tabbuttons:hover {
    background-color:PURPLE;
}
.tabcontent{
 background: #ddd;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.activeTab { background-color:PURPLE } /* solution for a. */
.activeItem { display: block; }
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {    
    $('.tabbuttons').on('click', function() {
        $('.tabbuttons').removeClass('activeTab'); /* solution for a. */
        $(this).addClass('activeTab'); /* solution for a. */
        var i = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.items p').hide();
        $(i).show();
    });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9h5eqsuy/3/)

For question c.: use div's instead of paragraphs...

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be nearly working - though can you rewrite the jquery section to include the call for jquery? I can't seem to get the js working- in my setup I can only have one html file, one css file, and one js file.

Comment: You indeed need jQuery for it. Add thus to the head section of your HTML file `<script src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry LinkinTED, I meant to say I cant include any js in my html, only a raw html file and raw js file. Can I include that code in a js file with your original js?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

It is close but not quite there (and as I side note I probably would go a javascript option)

What you need to do  is create a hierarchical relationship between your links and targets. To do this put the link and it's related target in a container. I've then used absolute positioning to position the targets in a `stage` container. I also keep `item1` always displayed so it is present on page load, but has a lower `z-index` than the other items so they display on top of it.

Where this falls down is the `itme1` tab is not highlited on page load

```css
div.items p {
  display: none
}
div.items p:target {
  display: block
}
#stage {
  position: releative;
}
#stage>div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#stage .item {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  left: 8px;
  width: 90%
}
#stage #item1 .item {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
#stage>div:target .item {
  display: block;
}
.tabbuttons {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3195c1;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tabbuttons:hover,
:target .tabbuttons {
  background-color: PURPLE;
}
.tabcontent {
  background: #ddd;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
  <div id="item1">
    <a href="#item1" class="tabbuttons">item 1</a>
    <div class="item">
      <p class="tabcontent">... item 1...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="item2">
    <a href="#item2" class="tabbuttons">item 2</a>
    <div class="item">
      <p class="tabcontent">... item 2...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="item3">
    <a href="#item3" class="tabbuttons">item 3</a>
    <div class="item">
      <p id="item3" class="tabcontent">...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```